# When run the programme it says programme.exe stopped working

Tags: c++, function, recursion

My programme is pretty simple i'm making a recursive programme i want it to call it self again and again until the task is completed it compiles just fine but it always says that  "programme.exe stopped working"

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
double factorial (double);
main ()
{
    double n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << factorial (n);
}
double factorial (double n)
{
    return (n * factorial (n - 1));
}
```

Comment: Invalid [`main` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function). And infinite recursion. Please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). And enable verbose warnings and treat them as errors.

Comment: side note: you're not allowed to define `main` with no return type. => `int main() {`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need a stop condition for your factorial recursive function

```
double factorial (double n)
{   if(n<1) return 1;
    return (n * factorial (n - 1));
}
```

Comment: if(n<1) return 1; would be better

Comment: that's exactly what i thought but maybe he wants to go for larger numbers?

Comment: i'm feeling like an idiot right now it was in front of my eyes how can i make a mistake this obvious and thanks for both of u for pointing it out